# Hide or Deactivate the setting "Format Current View" and "Edit Current View" in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, list-view, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'd like to make sure that only the list owner (or if it is not possible otherwise the SharePoint Owner) is able to see the settings "Format Current View" and "Edit Current View" when clicking on the view option.

Members should not be able to see this settings. How would I be able to achieve this goal?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

"Format Current View" and "Edit Current View" options will be visible for users having **Edit** or higher permissions.

As SharePoint default "Members" group has "Edit" permissions on site, they will see this options by default.

---

**Recommended Solution**:

Grant **Contribute** permissions to normal users of list. They will be able to add/edit/delete list items but will not be able to change anything in list and list view settings.

If you want to hide these options from only one list, you can break permissions inheritance for respective list and change Members permissions from Edit to Contribute.

If you want to hide these options from all lists in site, you have to change the Members permissions at site level itself.

Comment: Thanks. The "Edit Current View" is gone now. However, the "Format Current View" is still active. Would it be able to deactivate the whole button where it says "All Items"?

Comment: Not possible to hide it using SharePoint out of the box capabilities

Comment: So the "Format Current view" is also not hideable?

Comment: Hiding complete "All Items" menu is not possible. "Format Current view" will be hidden if you grant Read permissions. In this case, users will not be able to add/edit/delete items.